# What is Autoloader_Patch in Magento.php

Tags: magento-1.9, composer, phpunit

I have setup `phpunit` using `composer` to do some testing in `Magento`.

And after the setup I see the following lines added to my `Mage.php` file.

```
/** AUTOLOADER PATCH **/
if (file_exists($autoloaderPath = BP . DS . 'vendor/autoload.php') ||
    file_exists($autoloaderPath = BP . DS . '../vendor/autoload.php')
) {
    require $autoloaderPath;
}
/** AUTOLOADER PATCH **/
```

**What I want to know is what is the purpose of this patch, and can we do anything without changing our `Mage.php` file.**

My `composer.json`, which I used for installing `phpunit` is as follows :

```
{
"name": "company)name/api",
"type": "project",
"require": {
    "magento-hackathon/magento-composer-installer": "*"
},
"require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.5",
    "phpunit/php-invoker": "^2.0"
},
"extra": {
    "magento-root-dir": "/var/www/html/parent_project_dir"
},
"config": {
    "platform": {
        "ext-pcntl": "7.2",
        "ext-posix": "7.2"
    }
}
```

}

PS : I am using `Magento 1.9`.